# Apache 2.4 - Virtualhost Ignored?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

Using: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

I have setup my first site, and it works flawlessly. I'm now trying to setup my second site, but it seems to not load the configuration for it. I have done a2ensite.

Both configs are the same, but using different IPs, doc roots, and certs.

```
Listen x.x.x.x:80
Listen x.x.x.x:443
Listen [x:x:x:x]:80
Listen [x:x:x:x]:443

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80 [x:x:x:x]:80>
        ServerName site1.com
        Redirect permanent / https://site1.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443 [x:x:x:x]:443>
        ServerName site1.com
        ServerAlias www.site1.com
        DocumentRoot /www/site1.com/www

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/site1.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/site1.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/site1.com.ca-bundle

        <Directory /www/site1.com/www>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: When troubleshooting virtual host configuration, start with the output of the command "apachectl -S". Put this in your post if you would like further help analysing it.